# access object in array for POST method

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a POST method via mongo/mongoose:

```
Department
    .create({
        name: req.body.name,
        link: req.body.link,
        state: req.body.state,
        requirements: req.body.requirements,
        salary: req.body.salary,
        description: req.body.description
    })
```

requirements is an object containing other items:

```
requirements: {
    age: 21,
    citizenship: "yes",
    degree: "4-year"
}
```

Prior to creating I am checking that all fields were provided:

```
router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
const requiredFields = ["name", "link", "state", "age", "citizenship", "degree" "salary", "description"];
for(let i=0; i < requiredFields.length; i++){
    const field = requiredFields[i];
    if(!(field in req.body)){
        const message = `Missing \`${field}\` field in request body`;
        console.error(message);
        return res.status(400).send(message);
    };
};
```

Due to `age`, `citizenship`, and `degree` being object items, I cannot put their string inside the requiredFields. It errors out at `Missing age field in request body`. Any idea how to check that they were provided in req.body?

Comment: I will use something like a [revalidator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/revalidator) for validating the request body.

Answer (score 0):

1. To access the nested object you may save your required field as "requirement.age" instead of "age" and then may be use the get function in lodash library. So your condition would become:

`

```js
if (typeof(_.get(req.body, "requirement.age") === 'undefined')) {
  //Missing field    
}
```

`

2. You can try to flatten the req.body structure like:

```js
Object.assign(req.body, req.body.requirement)

// This would make your req.body look like 

{
  name: 'x',
  link: 'y',
  requirement: {
    age: 1
    ..
  },
  age: 1
  ..
}
```

Or you may assign it to another variable and then use.

```js
let reqBodyReplica = Object.assign({}, req.body, req.body,requirement)
```